# Can we run an iPhone app on iPad device during development?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios8.4

Hi I have been developing an universal application i.e. both for iPad and iPhone. Currently, I have been facing an issue in the iPhone build and I want to check it in the real device, however I have an old iPhone 4 and I can't check the issue that is coming up in iOS 8.4.

I need to know is there a way I can run my iPhone build on my iPad air 2. If so, could you please let me know what are the steps I need to do. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to run app on iPad device using XCODE or iTunes?

Comment: @SidShah Yes I did try.. And I did try to look up over the internet too, wasn't able to find a relevant answer so posted a question here. Thanks.

Comment: @Sujania I would like to run the app using XCode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can run iPhone build on  iPad device.

Under deployment info set devices as **iPhone** to test for iPhone device version as shown below and and run on your iPad air 2 device :

[image]

set devices as **iPad** to test for iPad vesrion and run on your iPad air 2 device

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can under given condition :

**Condition**

- Your app should be work on iPhone-4 properly .
- Your iPad UDID added in your provisioning profile . (If UDID is not added then select provisioning profile as Automatic and Certificate as Development but some time it will not work) .

*If both above condition is true for your app then you can easily RUN on iPad too .*

Answer (score 0):

you can directly set Active Scheme to iPad 2 and run your application for testing.
But if your making designing then you need to make different xib files for ipad and iphone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can because apps that are developed for the iPhone work fine on an iPad. You must add your "ipad air" UDID to your iTunes account for testing before you can download the Provisioning profile.